# How should I convert my Java code into J-meter BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I have small piece of Java code, which i have to incorporate into Jmeter to convert image into base64.

```
      File f =  new File("C:/Users/SETU BASAK/Desktop/a.jpg");
         String encodstring = encodeFileToBase64Binary(f);
         System.out.println(encodstring);
   }

   private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(File file){
        String encodedfile = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            encodedfile = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes).toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return encodedfile;
    }
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: You can paste this code, as it is in beanshell preprocessor. Don't forget to add all imports at the beginning. BTW JSR223 is recommended https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices#bsh_scripting

Answer (score 1):

Build your file as a jar file and place inside lib folder in apache-jmeter package.
Then add BeanShell Sampler in your script and add object for your class and pass your file inside method to get base64 value

in **BeanShell Sampler**, 
For ex your class name is Base64Conv means

```
import com.package.converter;

Base64Conv converter=new Base64Conv();
String imageBase64=converter.encodeFileToBase64Binary(new File("path to your file"));
```

then use ${imageBase64} wherever you required

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use JMeter built-in [test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) or [functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) as this way you will have maximum performance and minimum resources consumption so you can consider using [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) functions combination like:

```
${__base64Encode(${__FileToString(c:/Users/SETU BASAK/Desktop/a.jpg,,)},)}
```

You can install `__base64Encode()` and other custom functions using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

If you still want to go for scripting consider using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the relevant code would be something like:

```
new File("C:/Users/SETU BASAK/Desktop/a.jpg").getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
```

The both approaches should result into the same Base64 string:

[image]